# SQL Server - pull X random records per state

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with records for each zip code in the united states. For the purposes of displaying on a map, I need to select X random records per state. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
WITH sample AS (
 SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.state
                               ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rank
   FROM ZIPCODES t)
SELECT s.*
  FROM sample s
 WHERE s.rank <= 5
```

Comment: This works quite well. Next question - if by some chance I am required to port this to MySQL - is there a more generally compatible way to form the query?

Comment: @Chris: Not as-is - MySQL doesn't have analytic/ranking function support.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ZipCodes ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about newid. My question was how to pull random records for each state.